# ISPConfig does not show hard disk space used

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server

ISPConfig Version: 3.0.5.3 OS: Debian 7 (wheezy)

I have a problem with my ISPConfig installation.

We have about a hundred websites setup on our server and space is becoming a bit of an issue and we'd like to see which websites are using up more space than others. The problem is I cannot see how much space a website is using when navigating to the sites tab -> Website Quota.

For example, example.com has *blank* Used space, *Unlimited* soft limit and *Unlimited* hard limit despite setting the hard disk quota limit in the web domain page for each website.

I have root access to our server, so I am able to check directory size using `du -hs` but its a pain to go through and check each websites directory manually this way and I would like to see each websites hard disk usage in a user friendly way.

So, how do I fix ISPConfig so that I am able to view user disk usage in the control panel?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are all sites using space under a common root directory? If so, anyone of the `df`-like graphical utilities listed here, http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-analyze-your-disk-usage-pattern-in-linux/   ought to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I've reworded the question. I realized I hadn't actually asked what I wanted fixed. The resource you linked is interesting though, are any of those programs usable on a remote server? They all seemed like they have graphical interfaces.